# How to resolve a "Metadata error: chr must be valid" error on Linux?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am relatively new to the world of coding, so I am having trouble resolving an issue when running `TranslocWrapper.pl tutorial_metadata.txt preprocess/ results/ --threads 2`. I am trying to run the HTGTS Pipeline according to this [GitHub project](http://robinmeyers.github.io/transloc_pipeline/thedocs.html). This is the full error:

```
.   Library Genome  Chr Start   End Strand
1   RAG1A_SRep2 hg19    chr11   36594878    36595030    -
Metadata error: chr must be valid at /home/micah/transloc_pipeline/bin/TranslocWrapper.pl line 285.
    main::check_validity_of_metadata('HASH(0x2903ac8)') called at /home/micah/transloc_pipeline/bin/TranslocWrapper.pl line 248
    main::read_in_meta_file() called at /home/micah/transloc_pipeline/bin/TranslocWrapper.pl line 90
```

I have already double-checked the successful installation of the Software Dependencies, so everything should be all good, but I am having trouble interpreting the "Metadata error: chr must be valid at ..." line. If it helps, these are the specific lines that are being called in the error:

- TranslocWrapper.pl line 285:

  ```
  croak "Metadata error: chr must be valid" unless grep { $_ eq $expt->{chr} } @chrlist;
  ```
- TranslocWrapper.pl line 248:

  ```
  check_validity_of_metadata($expt);
  ```
- TranslocWrapper.pl line 90:

  ```
  read_in_meta_file;
  ```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This error is something specific to the particular library you're using, it's not a generic error.

Comment: Yeah, this looks more like application support than a programming question.

Comment: `select( (select(STDOUT), $| = 1 )[0] );` at the top of the script. This doesn't bode well (I'd write that line as simply `STDOUT->autoflush(1);`).

Comment: `IO::File->new("<$meta_file")` - Two-argument open, but in OO style. Why :-(

Comment: My interpretation of the error is that the index file (probably called `...something.../hg19/hg19.fa.index`) of the genome assembly (probably called `...something.../hg19/hg19.fa`) doesn't contain an entry corresponding to `chr11`.

Comment: My guess goes in the same way as @melpomene comment. I think you have an input that contains chromosomes called "chr1" while the reference genome used uses chromosomes called "1" (or the other way around). Make sure that you use the same reference for all the analysis. Naming schemes varies between the different sources(UCSC!=NCBI).

Answer (score 1):

So the error is saying that one of the sequence characters in the metadata file is not present in the sequence's assembly file.

Given that this is the provided example you should assume that the data is correct and your invocation is faulty.

Have you done the `TranslocPreprocess.pl` preprocessing steps?

If you have try looking at the first line of the metadata file, identify the assembly entry. Ensure that the assembly file exists and that it contains the required sequence.

One common problem with this kind of code is the case of the filenames. The examples are designed to be run in Linux where filename case matters. Windows likes to pretend that case doesn't matter, this can cause problems. If you are running this code from Microsoft Windows or extracted any of the archives from within Windows this is a likely cause of the error.